# Inheriting properties from prototype

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

```
function classA(){}; 

classA.prototype.age =25;

var obj = new classA();

console.log(obj.age)  //returns 25
```

Now, when I do:

```
classA.prototype = {};
```

Why `obj.age` is still returning `25`?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you pointed the `classA.prototype` to a **new object** but you didn't change the object that `obj.prototype` points to.

What is happening is:

```
classA.prototype ------> A
// create object with new classA()
// now its prototype also points to A
obj.prototype    ------> A    // points to the same prototype
```

now you reasign the prototype of `classA`

```
classA.prototype ------> B
```

but the prototype of `obj` still points to `A` (it was never changed)

```
obj.prototype    ------> A
```

So all you did was change the prototype reference of `classA` **after** the prototype reference for `obj` was already established.

If you want to have `obj` see the changes on the prototype, then **change the object it references (`A` in the example above) and not the reference itself**:

Sample code:

```js
function classA(){}; 

classA.prototype.age =25;

var obj = new classA();

console.log(obj.age)   // 25

// change the object itself, not the reference
delete classA.prototype.age;

console.log(obj.age); // undefined
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the prototype of object also?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in the following order:

```
function classA(){}; 

classA.prototype.age = 25;
classA.prototype = {};

var obj = new classA();
console.log(obj.age)  // returns undefined
```

The result will be indeed your excepted behavior. It depends on when you set the prototype of the classA function. This will be demonstrated by the following code snippet:

```
function classA(){}; 

classA.prototype.age = 25;

var obj1 = new classA();

classA.prototype = {};

var obj2 = new classA();

console.log(obj1.age)  // returns 25
console.log(obj2.age)  // returns undefined
```

Hence, a `object` is only affected by the changes to a `prototype` of a function, when this happens before the `object's` creation.

Answer (score 0):

reassigning your `prototype` after creating the object has no effect on the previously created object , it will still have the old `prototype` when it was created. New `prototye` will only effect newly created objects